# Is it possible to use Google Workspace (formerly G Suite) as Identity Provider for AWS WorkSpaces using SAML 2.0?

Tags: amazon-web-services, google-workspace, amazon-workspaces

Is it possible to use **Google Workspace** (formerly G Suite) as Identity Provider for **AWS WorkSpaces** using SAML 2.0? **(without using AWS-SSO)**

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible. You can add AWS as a custom SAML app in the Google Workspace Admin console

Even here you can find the details in the official documentation from AWS

[How to use G Suite as an external identity provider for AWS SSO](https://aws.amazon.com/es/blogs/security/how-to-use-g-suite-as-external-identity-provider-aws-sso/)

And here you can find more details about [Adding a custom SAML app in Google Workspace](https://support.google.com/a/answer/6087519?hl=en)

If you have any questions please let me know